# How to request LinkedIn to enable webhooks for my app?

Tags: linkedin-api, webhooks

I'm trying to enable webhook support for my Linkedin app (in the developer portal) and I can see in the docs:

[Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/webhook-validation)

> The Webhooks tab is only enabled for applications with a use case for webhooks.

I haven't found a way to request access for this specific functionality.

There is no Webhooks tab in my app settings (in the developer portal) and I cannot find a way to enable/configure anything related to webhooks.

Thanks,

Iulian

Comment: Please share more details on what problem you are facing and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have created a Linkedin app in the developer portal and I'm trying to enable webhook support. In my app settings there is no way to enable or configure webhook support.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the option to setup webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g24cZ.jpg)

You can navigate to the below url
[https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/{app_id}/webhooks](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/%7Bapp_id%7D/webhooks)
Replace {app_id} by your app id

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).